# Excel Import: Param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel-import

I don't know why but from one day to the other my excel import doesn't work anymore.

View:

```
<h1>Import Data</h1>
<br>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <center>
    <h2>Import List</h2>
    <br>
    <%= form_tag import_marcels_path, multipart: true do %>
      <%= file_field_tag :file %>
      <br>
      <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
    <% end %>
  </center>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
def import
  Marcel.import(params[:file])

  redirect_to root_url, notice: 'File imported.'
end

def create
  @marcel = Marcel.new(marcel_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @marcel.save
      format.html { redirect_to @marcel, notice: 'Marcel was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @marcel }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @marcel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def marcel_params
  params.require(:marcel).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :ldap)
end
```

Model:

```
class Marcel < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.import(file)
      spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
      header = spreadsheet.row(1)
      (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
        marcel = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
        marcel.attributes = row.to_hash
        marcel.save!
      end
    end

    def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
      case File.extname(file.original_filename)
      when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
      when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
      when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
      else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
      end
    end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
  # resources :marcels do
  #     collection do
  #       post :import
  #     end
  # end

  get 'marcels' => 'marcels#index'
  post 'import_marcels' => 'marcels#import'
```

Now I receive the the following error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: marcel

 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
 def marcel_params
   params.require(:marcel).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :ldap)
 end end

{"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token" => "tR2XHWpu1RB58fGMlAQQKXcQDD8ka8alVpTFztd7G5crgF0UfYwZHUNUN6+NsRF3AocT+2ljEZFNE2i+19Sfbw==",
"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f2cac0c2cb0
@tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20180322-6630-1fsopb3.csv>, 
@original_filename="test.csv", 
@content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";
filename=\"test.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel\r\n">,
"commit"=>"Import"}
```

I don't know why it happens now but maybe someone of you have an idea how I can fix that. I excluded *.require(:marcel)* from def marcel_params. After the import no error occurs but the values of the Excel are not save in the database.

Comment: Where is the action `marcels_path` responds to?, also, by using a `form_tag` doesn't add the marcel key containing the needed values to your params. You still need to permit `file` if you're planning work with those params.

Comment: When you look in your logfile... and look at an example of the form submit. What params come through? What params are you expecting instead?

Comment: @SebastianPalma added the part of the routes.rb. So you think I have to permit :file?Strange is, that this worked before without permitting file.

Comment: @TarynEast what do you mean with logfile? Where can I find it? Added Parameterslog of error site

Comment: The logfiles are generally found in `/log/development.log` or similar.

Comment: @TarynEast unfortunately same information like in the Errorlog which I added above

Comment: Ok, so the issue is that this part: `params.require(:marcel)` tells your controller "don't accept any params unless there's one that begins with `marcel`... 
so it's totally throwing away your file params, because that's what you're telling it to do.

To fix it, you need to tell your form, to start with `marcel` - and then the params will come through starting with `marcel` and your controller will be able to find them.

I'm not sure why that's not coming through with `marcels_path` - it might be worth you typing `marcels_path` into your console to see what it generates.

Comment: @TarynEast thanks for your help and explanations :) After you said that maybe it because of the path I used another way to create the routes. After this the import works fine. I updated the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to TarynEast I found a workaround for the issue. Something with the routes didn't work like expected so I changed the routes from:

```
  resources :marcels do
      collection do
        post :import
      end
  end
```

to this:

```
  get 'marcels' => 'marcels#index'
  post 'import_marcels' => 'marcels#import'
```

After this, the import works fine now.